# how to check data from 2 database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So im currently creating 2 database which is client and midwife. so at sign in page code, how should i modify the code so that i can check if the username and password inserted are from client or midwife ? thank you in advance.

databasehelper = client // databasehelper1 = midwife

here's my sign in code :

```
    _btnsignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            _username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
            _password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
            String str1 = _username.getText().toString();
            String str2 = _password.getText().toString();
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_9 + "=?", new String[]{str1, str2});
            //cursor1 = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper1.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper1.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper1.COL_9 + "=?", new String[]{str1, str2});
            if (cursor != null)
            {
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    Intent gotowelcome = new Intent(SIGN_IN.this, WELCOME.class);
                    gotowelcome.putExtra("Username", str1);
                    SIGN_IN.this.startActivity(gotowelcome);
                } else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to not have two databases but rather the 1 table in a databse, for users with an indicator for user type (midwife or client).

However, you could do something along the lines of:-

```
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper.COL_9 + "=?", new String[]{str1, str2});
    cursor1 = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper1.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper1.COL_2 + "=? AND " + DatabaseHelper1.COL_9 + "=?", new String[]{str1, str2});

    if(cursor.getCount() == 1 || cursor1.getCount() == 1) {
        boolean fromclient = (cursor.getCount == 1); //<<< check which type

        Intent gotowelcome ........        
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR",........
    }
```

Where .... represents code that you already have. The above does assume a unique user/password combination although you could determine this with something like:-

```
    boolean sameusernamepasswordforboth = (cursor.getCount() == 1 && cursor1.getCount() == 1);
```

or

```
    boolean sameusernamepasswordforboth = ((cursor.getCount() + cursor1.getCount()) > 1);
```